# simple code using OpenAPI and spring. However, my swagger page keep saying "No operations defined in spec!"

Tags: java, spring-boot, springdoc-openapi-ui, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

## I am pretty new with openApi generator. I generated a simple code using a yaml file. everything seems to run fine but when i am accessing the swagger page i am getting "No operations defined in spec!", i am unsure if i am missing a dependency or something in the code.

[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsghM.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjx1p.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6a33T.png)

I wrote the yaml file, added all the dependencies then did a mvn clean install which generated the code in my target folder and the code ran and compile. I was hoping to be able to render the swagger page properly for testing purposes

````
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-oas</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>
                                ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/demoFile.yml
                            </inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <apiPackage>com.code.openapi.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.code.openapi.model</modelPackage>
                            <supportingFilesToGenerate>
                                ApiUtil.java
                            </supportingFilesToGenerate>
                            <configOptions>
                                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                                <delegatePattern>false</delegatePattern>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.